# DI in .NET Core without ASP.NET Core

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core, daemon

I'm looking to write a daemon process using .NET Core which will basically act much like a cron job and just orchestrate API/DB calls on some interval. As such, it has no need to expose any web routes, so there's no need for ASP.NET Core.

However, afaik ASP.NET Core is where you get that nice `Startup` class with all the DI plumbing and environment-based configuration you might need.

The way I see it, I have two options:

1. Forgo ASP.NET Core and just hook up the DI framework on my own. If I go that route, how do I do that?
2. Include ASP.NET Core just for the DI portion, but then how do I spawn background tasks which "run forever" outside of any request context? My understanding is that the DI framework very much assumes there's some sort of incoming request to orchestrate all the injections.

Comment: Option 3. Use [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di/).

Comment: DI doesn't require ASP.NET. Startup isn't a requirement, it's just a convention. You can use the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.* packages directly

Answer (score 12):

You seem to pose multiple questions let me try to answer them one by one.

## Dependendency injection without Startup Class.

This is definitely possible. Since the `Startup` class is part of the WebHostBuilder package (which contains Kestrel/webserver). [The Dependency injection is nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/) is just a dependency on this package and so can be used alone in the following way:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddTransient<IMyInterface, MyClass>();
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider(); //ioc container
serviceProvider.GetService<IMyInterface>();
```

So at your program main (startup function) you can add this code and maybe even make the ServiceProvider Staticaly available.

Note that the IHostingEnvironment is also part of the kestrel package and not available to you, but there are simple workarounds for this.

### Registration

Im not sure what exactly you mean by spawning background tasks/running forever. But in dotnet you can spawn tasks with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` to tell the schedular that your task will be running very long and dotnet wel optimise threads for this. you can also use `serviceProvider` in these tasks.

The only downside to the DI is that you need to set it up at the startup of your application and cannot add new services while running your application (actually you can add to services and then rebuild the serviceProvider, but its easier using another external IOC container). If you where thinking of running some kind of plugin system where dependencies would automaticaly be registered, you're better of making your own factory method.

Also note when using plugins, when they are loaded in as dll's, they cannot be unloaded so if you have a theoretically unlimited amount of plugins, your memory will slowly build up every time you add new plugins.

Comment: "The only downside to the DI is that you need to set it up at the startup of your application and cannot add new services while running your application". I would say this is not a downside at all, since [Register-Resolve-Register is an anti-pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42562452/264697).

Comment: @Steven yes, i get that, but i was stating that to this particular case. I Understand the danger of having scoped registrations. It's still a possible feature to use, but you have to understand the dangers (and only use it when you really know what you are doing).

Comment: I'm not referring to the notion of Scoping at all. What I'm referring to is the notion of adding "new services while running your application", which is something you should simply never do. The notion of scoped registrations is something that the .NET Core DI supports, even though it does not allow updating the container while running. These two things are unrelated.

Comment: ServiceCollection does not contain a definition for AddSingleton so you NEED to add the nuget package which introduces these additional extensions

Answer (score 7):

> As of.NET Core 2.1 this can/should be done with a Generic Host. From
>   .NET Core docs:

"The goal of the Generic Host is to decouple the HTTP pipeline from the Web Host API to enable a wider array of host scenarios..."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.1

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
  var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>

    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
       // ...
    });

  await builder.RunConsoleAsync();
}
```